# How to post file to Blobstore using ios (objective-c) client

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to upload file to blobstore using ios (objective-c) client.
Server is servlet. Please demo handle on server and client.
Please guide me to solve this problem.Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you want someone else to do the work, please provide more information on your application and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great post on using Blobstore with an iOS client. If you provided more information I could know how well it applies in your case.

https://brunofuster.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/uploading-an-image-from-iphone-to-appengine-blobstore-using-vraptor/